# Gmail API: Triggering in-webpage refresh

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'd like to trigger the in-webpage refresh button programmatically for the purpose of [applying labels to emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462409/gmail-api-asynchronous-label-update-application/31462505#31462505) without making the user manually refresh the page or make some other page action in order to see the labels. Is this possible to do? All of the documentation I am finding is surrounding refresh tokens, which is obviously something different.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do that from the Gmail REST API (i.e. trigger refresh action in web browser viewing the gmail page).  If you're running as a browser extension on the other hand, then sure.